# Internal Links breaking Website Structure

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a website (in Wordpress) that has the header between the content and footer, which is then absolutely positioned to appear as you would expect. This worked flawlessly, until I tried to use the comment internal links.

If you click an internal comment link it moves the content area up (through/under the header), instead of moving the screen down to where the comment is. You can view it in action here: http://peterbooker.com/blog/  by clicking on '1 Comment'. Either from the blog page or the specific posts page.

I cannot find a way to prevent this using CSS, but is there a way I could prevent this using JavaScript and/or anything else?

I would really like to get this working and I would appreciate any help/advice/guidance.

Comment: Please post code you think is causing an issue!

Comment: Everything seems to be fine to me? When you click "1 comment" it takes you to the comments page, which doesn't have the blog post on.

Comment: The blog post is there, it is just under the header (and off the top of the page). This is the unintended behavior.

Comment: It is not any specific code, more the behavior of html when there is no header above the content. There is a margin-top above the page (which creates space for the header to be absolutely positioned into).

When the comment link is clicked, this stops working and the content is pushed up behind the header.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your CSS is really weird, but you can fix the issue with:

- Remove overflow: hidden; from main and use a div to clear the floats after secondary div.
- Remove the whole padding-bottom: 5000px; margin-bottom: -5000px; from secondary... it makes no sense.

And then you can just fiddle to get it right. But the overflow hidden is causing your problem here.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go.

For reference, the large padding and margins create the illusion that the sidebar is as long as the content area, even if it is not. Quite useful!

Comment: Yeah but that's a really weird to go around doing it, and to achieve that you have to use overflow: hidden; which breaks your site. A common technique for giving the illusion that they are as long is to use a background image (in your case, a line positioned in the right place) for the parent div containing both primary and secondary divs.

Comment: Your fix worked perfectly, thank you riku. I will attempt to find a way to continue using the margin/padding trick, every opportunity to avoid using an image is good.